# View slow with only 40K rows - Hierarchy type data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am desperately trying to my a view a lot quicker. The data I am looking at is a Location table. Each location (except the root nodes) have a ParentID, which is a self join.

The table has 40K rows. I have attempted to add a good covering index. But when selecting a single row, I'm getting a response of 250ms. I've checked the query plan, it's there's nothing that stands out, except a lot of items at 2% (Adding to 100% of the time).

In an attempt to get help, I have created a script that creates a very similar table (Only 'description' changes, due to privacy). It has the same indexes and table structure. It also has the same View I use.

The view returns a row for each unique location.
The view also has the name of the Location that's being looked at.

The file has all the data - so 40K rows... and is 4.5Meg. It takes 4 minutes to run to insert the exact data.

I've hosted the SQL script here. It's 40K lines, so... I thought this would be best.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avhw2DacCYPugsJckaO-Mo9cwNTLpA

Is there anyway to make this view a lot quicker. I'm really looking at below 50ms - hopefully less.

I've thought of an indexed view, but as I'm using UNION, I can't. If I used a recursive CTE, there's a UNION, so again, can't. I think my indexing is suitable, but not giving the performance I need.

Are there any other ways I can get this view performance increased?

It's all in the SQL file, but here's the main structure.

```
CREATE TABLE MyLocations 
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentId INT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    IsDeleted BIT NOT NULL,
    LocationLevel INT NOT NULL
) 

ALTER TABLE MyLocations ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Loop FOREIGN KEY (ParentId)  REFERENCES MyLocations(Id)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Location_LocationType] ON [dbo].[MyLocations]
(
    [LocationLevel] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Location_ParentLocationId_INCLUDES] ON [dbo].[MyLocations]
(
    [ParentId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Id],
    [Description],
    [LocationLevel],
    [IsDeleted]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwMyLocations]
WITH SchemaBinding

AS
    /*
       SELECT * FROM vwMyLocations
    */
    WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT
        l1.Id as LocationId,
        l1.LocationLevel, 
        l1.ParentId,
        l1.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted,
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        NULL AS Level2, 
        NULL AS Level3,
        NULL AS Level4,
        NULL AS Level5,
        NULL AS Level6,
        NULL AS Level7,
        NULL AS Level8,
        NULL AS Level9,
        NULL AS Level10
    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    WHERE l1.LocationLevel = 1

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        l2.Id AS LocationId,
        l2.LocationLevel,
        l2.ParentId,
        l2.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted, 
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        l2.Description AS Level2, 
        NULL AS Level3,
        NULL AS Level4,
        NULL AS Level5,
        NULL AS Level6,
        NULL AS Level7,
        NULL AS Level8,
        NULL AS Level9,
        NULL AS Level10
    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l2
        ON l2.ParentId = l1.Id
    WHERE l2.LocationLevel = 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        l3.Id AS LocationId,
        l3.LocationLevel,
        l3.ParentId,
        l3.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted | l3.IsDeleted,
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        l2.Description AS Level2, 
        l3.Description AS Level3,
        NULL AS Level4,
        NULL AS Level5,
        NULL AS Level6,
        NULL AS Level7,
        NULL AS Level8,
        NULL AS Level9,
        NULL AS Level10
    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l2
        ON l2.ParentId = l1.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l3
        ON l3.ParentId = l2.Id
    WHERE l3.LocationLevel = 3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        l4.Id AS LocationId,
        l4.LocationLevel,
        l4.ParentId,
        l4.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted | l3.IsDeleted | l4.IsDeleted,
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        l2.Description AS Level2, 
        l3.Description AS Level3,
        l4.Description AS Level4,
        NULL AS Level5,
        NULL AS Level6,
        NULL AS Level7,
        NULL AS Level8,
        NULL AS Level9,
        NULL AS Level10

    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l2
        ON l2.ParentId = l1.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l3
        ON l3.ParentId = l2.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l4
        ON l4.ParentId = l3.Id
    WHERE l4.LocationLevel = 4

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        l5.Id AS LocationId,
        l5.LocationLevel,
        l5.ParentId,
        l5.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted | l3.IsDeleted | l4.IsDeleted | l5.IsDeleted,
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        l2.Description AS Level2, 
        l3.Description AS Level3,
        l4.Description AS Level4,
        l5.Description AS Level5,
        NULL AS Level6,
        NULL AS Level7,
        NULL AS Level8,
        NULL AS Level9,
        NULL AS Level10

    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l2
        ON l2.ParentId = l1.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l3
        ON l3.ParentId = l2.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l4
        ON l4.ParentId = l3.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l5
        ON l5.ParentId = l4.Id
    WHERE l5.LocationLevel = 5

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        l6.Id AS LocationId,
        l6.LocationLevel,
        l6.ParentId,
        l6.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted | l3.IsDeleted | l4.IsDeleted | l5.IsDeleted | l6.IsDeleted,
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        l2.Description AS Level2, 
        l3.Description AS Level3,
        l4.Description AS Level4,
        l5.Description AS Level5,
        l6.Description AS Level6,
        NULL AS Level7,
        NULL AS Level8,
        NULL AS Level9,
        NULL AS Level10

    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l2
        ON l2.ParentId = l1.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l3
        ON l3.ParentId = l2.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l4
        ON l4.ParentId = l3.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l5
        ON l5.ParentId = l4.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l6
        ON l6.ParentId = l5.Id
    WHERE l6.LocationLevel = 6

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        l7.Id AS LocationId,
        l7.LocationLevel,
        l7.ParentId,
        l7.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted | l3.IsDeleted | l4.IsDeleted | l5.IsDeleted | l6.IsDeleted | l7.IsDeleted,
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        l2.Description AS Level2, 
        l3.Description AS Level3,
        l4.Description AS Level4,
        l5.Description AS Level5,
        l6.Description AS Level6,
        l7.Description AS Level7,
        NULL AS Level8,
        NULL AS Level9,
        NULL AS Level10

    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l2
        ON l2.ParentId = l1.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l3
        ON l3.ParentId = l2.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l4
        ON l4.ParentId = l3.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l5
        ON l5.ParentId = l4.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l6
        ON l6.ParentId = l5.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l7
        ON l7.ParentId = l6.Id
     AND l7.LocationLevel = 7

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        l8.Id AS LocationId,
        l8.LocationLevel,
        l8.ParentId,
        l8.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted | l3.IsDeleted | l4.IsDeleted | l5.IsDeleted | l6.IsDeleted | l7.IsDeleted | l8.IsDeleted,
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        l2.Description AS Level2, 
        l3.Description AS Level3,
        l4.Description AS Level4,
        l5.Description AS Level5,
        l6.Description AS Level6,
        l7.Description AS Level7,
        l8.Description AS Level8,
        NULL AS Level9,
        NULL AS Level10

    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l2
        ON l2.ParentId = l1.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l3
        ON l3.ParentId = l2.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l4
        ON l4.ParentId = l3.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l5
        ON l5.ParentId = l4.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l6
        ON l6.ParentId = l5.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l7
        ON l7.ParentId = l6.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l8
        ON l8.ParentId = l7.Id
    WHERE l8.LocationLevel = 8

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        l9.Id AS LocationId,
        l9.LocationLevel,
        l9.ParentId,
        l9.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted | l3.IsDeleted | l4.IsDeleted | l5.IsDeleted | l6.IsDeleted | l7.IsDeleted | l8.IsDeleted | l9.IsDeleted,
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        l2.Description AS Level2, 
        l3.Description AS Level3,
        l4.Description AS Level4,
        l5.Description AS Level5,
        l6.Description AS Level6,
        l7.Description AS Level7,
        l8.Description AS Level8,
        l9.Description AS Level9,
        NULL AS Level10

    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l2
        ON l2.ParentId = l1.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l3
        ON l3.ParentId = l2.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l4
        ON l4.ParentId = l3.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l5
        ON l5.ParentId = l4.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l6
        ON l6.ParentId = l5.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l7
        ON l7.ParentId = l6.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l8
        ON l8.ParentId = l7.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l9
        ON l9.ParentId = l8.Id
    WHERE l9.LocationLevel = 9

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        l10.Id AS LocationId,
        l10.LocationLevel,
        l10.ParentId,
        l10.Description AS thisLocationName,
        l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted | l3.IsDeleted | l4.IsDeleted | l5.IsDeleted | l6.IsDeleted | l7.IsDeleted | l8.IsDeleted | l9.IsDeleted | l10.IsDeleted,
        l1.Description AS Level1, 
        l2.Description AS Level2, 
        l3.Description AS Level3,
        l4.Description AS Level4,
        l5.Description AS Level5,
        l6.Description AS Level6,
        l7.Description AS Level7,
        l8.Description AS Level8,
        l9.Description AS Level9,
        l10.Description AS Level10

    FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l2
        ON l2.ParentId = l1.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l3
        ON l3.ParentId = l2.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l4
        ON l4.ParentId = l3.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l5
        ON l5.ParentId = l4.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l6
        ON l6.ParentId = l5.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l7
        ON l7.ParentId = l6.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l8
        ON l8.ParentId = l7.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l9
        ON l9.ParentId = l8.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].MyLocations l10
        ON l10.ParentId = l9.Id
    WHERE l10.LocationLevel = 10
    )
    SELECT
        cte.LocationId,
        cte.LocationLevel,
        cte.IsDeleted,
        lt.DisplayName,
        cte.ParentId,
        cte.thisLocationName,
        cte.Level1, 
        cte.Level2, 
        cte.Level3,
        cte.Level4,
        cte.Level5,
        cte.Level6,
        cte.Level7,
        cte.Level8,
        cte.Level9,
        cte.Level10
     FROM cte
    INNER JOIN ref.LocationType lt
    ON lt.Id = cte.LocationLevel

GO
```

I attempted a CTE like this, but the response time seemed to decay.

```
with h as (
    select l.Id, l.ParentId, l.Description, l.LocationLevel, l.IsDeleted
             , convert(varchar(100), null) l2desc
             , convert(varchar(100), null) l3desc
    from MyLocation l
    where ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    select l.Id, l.ParentId, l.Description, l.LocationLevel, l.IsDeleted
            , case when l.LocationLevel = 2 then l.Description when l.LocationLevel > 2 then h.Description end  l2desc
            , case when l.LocationLevel = 3 then l.Description when l.LocationLevel > 3 then h.Description end  l3desc
    from h
    inner join MyLocation l on l.ParentId = h.id
    )
select
*
from h
order by LocationLevel, ParentId
;
```

Comment: have you tried recursive CTE ?

Comment: I have @Squirrel - But the response was worse. I can include the CTE attempt in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have limited levels, maybe this might help

```
select  LocationId      = lc1.Id,
    LocationLevel       = lc1.LocationLevel,
    IsDeleted       = lc1.IsDeleted,
    DisplayName     = lt.DisplayName,
    ParentId        = lc1.ParentId,
    thisLocationName    = lc1.Description,
    Level1          = coalesce( case when lc5.LocationLevel = 1 then lc5.Description end,
                        case when lc4.LocationLevel = 1 then lc4.Description end,
                        case when lc3.LocationLevel = 1 then lc3.Description end,
                        case when lc2.LocationLevel = 1 then lc2.Description end,
                        case when lc1.LocationLevel = 1 then lc1.Description end
                        ),
    Level2          = coalesce( case when lc5.LocationLevel = 2 then lc5.Description end,
                        case when lc4.LocationLevel = 2 then lc4.Description end,
                        case when lc3.LocationLevel = 2 then lc3.Description end,
                        case when lc2.LocationLevel = 2 then lc2.Description end,
                        case when lc1.LocationLevel = 2 then lc1.Description end
                        ),
    Level3          = coalesce( case when lc5.LocationLevel = 3 then lc5.Description end,
                        case when lc4.LocationLevel = 3 then lc4.Description end,
                        case when lc3.LocationLevel = 3 then lc3.Description end,
                        case when lc2.LocationLevel = 3 then lc2.Description end,
                        case when lc1.LocationLevel = 3 then lc1.Description end
                        ),
    Level4          = coalesce( case when lc5.LocationLevel = 4 then lc5.Description end,
                        case when lc4.LocationLevel = 4 then lc4.Description end,
                        case when lc3.LocationLevel = 4 then lc3.Description end,
                        case when lc2.LocationLevel = 4 then lc2.Description end,
                        case when lc1.LocationLevel = 4 then lc1.Description end
                        ),
    Level5          = coalesce( case when lc5.LocationLevel = 5 then lc5.Description end,
                        case when lc4.LocationLevel = 5 then lc4.Description end,
                        case when lc3.LocationLevel = 5 then lc3.Description end,
                        case when lc2.LocationLevel = 5 then lc2.Description end,
                        case when lc1.LocationLevel = 5 then lc1.Description end
                        )
from    MyLocations lc1
    left join MyLocations lc2   on  lc1.ParentId        = lc2.Id
    left join MyLocations lc3   on  lc2.ParentId        = lc3.Id
    left join MyLocations lc4   on  lc3.ParentId        = lc4.Id
    left join MyLocations lc5   on  lc4.ParentId        = lc5.Id
    left join MyLocations lc6   on  lc5.ParentId        = lc6.Id
    left join MyLocations lc7   on  lc6.ParentId        = lc7.Id
    left join MyLocations lc8   on  lc7.ParentId        = lc8.Id
    left join MyLocations lc9   on  lc8.ParentId        = lc9.Id
    left join MyLocations lc10  on  lc9.ParentId        = lc10.Id
    inner join LocationType lt  on  lc1.LocationLevel   = lt.Id
```

Comment: I think you nailed it!!! I'm just testing, but that is way faster!! In fact, profiler is reporting 0ms! I'm looking into it though, to make sure I've done it right, but that's amazing. I was worried all the left joins would cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `CTE` is not required here so you can store all the data in temporary as below using `INTO` clause and select final query from there. I am sure it will minimize time: but you have to manage it to keep somewhere and final query will be only written in the view.

```
SELECT
    l1.Id as LocationId,
    l1.LocationLevel, 
    l1.ParentId,
    l1.Description AS thisLocationName,
    l1.IsDeleted,
    l1.Description AS Level1, 
    NULL AS Level2, 
    NULL AS Level3,
    NULL AS Level4,
    NULL AS Level5,
    NULL AS Level6,
    NULL AS Level7,
    NULL AS Level8,
    NULL AS Level9,
    NULL AS Level10
INTO #tmpLocation    
FROM [dbo].MyLocations l1
WHERE l1.LocationLevel = 1
UNION ALL
---------
---------
UNION ALL
--------
--------
```

Final Query will be:

```
SELECT
    cte.LocationId,
    cte.LocationLevel,
    cte.IsDeleted,
    lt.DisplayName,
    cte.ParentId,
    cte.thisLocationName,
    cte.Level1, 
    cte.Level2, 
    cte.Level3,
    cte.Level4,
    cte.Level5,
    cte.Level6,
    cte.Level7,
    cte.Level8,
    cte.Level9,
    cte.Level10
FROM #tmpLocation cte
INNER JOIN ref.LocationType lt ON lt.Id = cte.LocationLevel
```

Note: you can also add index on `LocationLevel` column of temporary table

Comment: Would this be the view? I can't use a stored procedure here, as I need to join to this view.

Comment: Obviously No, first try it, if it helps you in anyway then we can have many alternative ways to execute it in your way. We  can use `JOB` to call that query and dump result in one `table` then we can join this and select record from the view.